# Using Unbound DACs in Process graph fails to run Processing functions

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating a Process to import items from an external API source into records in Acumatica.

I've created an unbound DAC that is used to represent the entries available from the external API.

```
[Serializable]
public class ImportItem : IBqlTable
{
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public bool? Selected { get; set; }
    public abstract class selected : IBqlField { }

    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "External Ref Nbr")]
    public string RefNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class refNbr : IBqlField { }
}
```

In a Process graph I implement the delegate of the main view to create and return the Resultset (normally generated from the API data). I then have a screen bound to this graph with a grid view that displays the items to allow the user to select the ones to import. The main Process delegate will then create the records in Acumatica for the selected items.

```
public class ImportItemsProcess : PXGraph<ImportItemsProcess>
{
    public PXProcessing<ImportItem> ImportItems;
    public PXCancel<ImportItem> Cancel;

    public ImportItemsProcess()
    {
        ImportItems.SetProcessCaption("Import");
        ImportItems.SetProcessAllCaption("Import All");
        ImportItems.SetProcessDelegate(ProcessImportItems);
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable importItems(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        PXResultset<ImportItem> items = new PXResultset<ImportItem>();

        /* Would create ImportItems from external API data here */
        items.Add(new PXResult<ImportItem>(new ImportItem() { RefNbr = "1" }));
        items.Add(new PXResult<ImportItem>(new ImportItem() { RefNbr = "2" }));
        items.Add(new PXResult<ImportItem>(new ImportItem() { RefNbr = "3" }));

        return items;
    }

    public static void ProcessImportItems(List<ImportItem> importItems)
    {
        throw new PXException("ProcessImportItems() has been called");
    }
}
```

And the ASPX page:

```
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" PrimaryView="ImportItems" TypeName="APIImporter.ImportItemsProcess" >
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
    <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="100%" Style="z-index: 100"
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSearch="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Primary" TabIndex="1500" TemporaryFilterCaption="Filter Applied">
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="ImportItems">
                <RowTemplate>
                    <px:PXCheckBox ID="edSelected" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="Selected" Text="Selected" CommitChanges="true">
                    </px:PXCheckBox>
                    <px:PXTextEdit ID="edRefNbr" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="RefNbr" DefaultLocale="">
                    </px:PXTextEdit>
                </RowTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" Width="60px" CommitChanges="true">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RefNbr">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

When written as the simplified example here the Process delegate is never invoked. I suspect is has something to do with when the Process button is clicked the callback to the server runs the view's delegate function that re-creates the list of ImportItem objects and that the framework can not relate the newly created objects to the ones in the postback without a Key field. However, if I add an IsKey attribute to the RefNbr of the DAC...

```
    [PXString(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "External Ref Nbr")]
    public string RefNbr { get; set; }
```

...now when selecting an item on the Screen I'm immediately given a line-level error with the message "Error: The argument is out of range. Parameter name: table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data view delegate, you have to add the items to the Cache in addition to returning them. Try below:

```
        protected virtual IEnumerable importItems()
        {    
            int iCachedData = 0;
            foreach (var row in ImportItems.Cache.Cached)
            {
                iCachedData++;
                yield return row;
            }

            if (iCachedData == 0)
            {
               for (int iCounter = 1; iCounter <= 5; iCounter++)
               {
                   ImportItem item = new ImportItem() { RefNbr = iCounter };
                   item = ImportItems.Insert(item);
                   ImportItems.Cache.SetStatus(item, PXEntryStatus.Held);
                   yield return item;
               }
            }
        }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding abstract classes for your DAC fields first. 
If that doesn't resolve your issue please add your ASPX code to your question.

```
[Serializable]
public class ImportItem : IBqlTable
{
    #region Selected
    public abstract class selected : IBqlField { }

    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public bool? Selected { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region RefNbr
    public abstract class refNbr : IBqlField { }

    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "External Ref Nbr")]
    public string RefNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I have tried with the abstract BQL classes and the result is the same. I've updated the original post with the classes and ASPX page.

Comment: I think the main issue is the unbound DAC. Replacing ImportItem: IBqlTable
 by ImportItem : SOShipment and having only this line in the delegate 'return PXSelect<ImportItem>.Select(this)' will invoke the process delegate.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but that doesn't work either. Having the ImportItem class derive from SOShipment results in an object (and then row in the grid) being generated for every SO Shipment in the database. This has nothing to do with any existing records at this stage -- I need to create the record objects from data retrieved via an API call.
In the View's delegate I tried to .Clear the cache and populate it with the manually created objects before a 'return PXSelect<ImportItems>.Select(this)' but no luck with that either.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Doesn't it call the process delegate? I understand this is not what you need to do but it's the minimum changes required to make the process delegate work when I test. I'm not able to make it work on unbound DAC because the Processing page generates query to the database. Hopefully someone can chime in and provide a confirmation of whether or not processing screens can work with unbound DAC.

Comment: Yes, changing it to derive from a database bound DAC does allow the delegate to be called. But I was looking for a way to handle such a situation without the necessity to maintain a database table of records that would have to be managed and synchronized with items from the external API.

Comment: Understood, we are on the same page. That's what I was trying to achieve, make the unbound DAC with delegate behave as a bound DAC so it works with processing screens. Unfortunately I wasn't able to succeed or find an example of a processing screen operating on an unbound table. Still trying to get confirmation on whether or not processing screens can support that. If I get any more info on this I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Processing Graph functionality Using Bound DAC but not Database Table. 
This is useful in the case when you want to Access some API and fetch the records in processing screen without saving into the Database. I am not including aspx code here.

The Highlight point in this code in [PXVirtualDAC] and the Key Field in DAC because of this we can achieve this functionality without creating a table. You can say that a Virtual DAC - without bound any database table.

```
public class TestUnboundProcessing : PXGraph<TestUnboundProcessing>
{
    #region Unbound DAC
    public class UnboundDAC : IBqlTable
    {
        #region Selected
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
        public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
        public abstract class selected : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true,IsKey =true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public abstract class id : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

        [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public abstract class author : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

        [PXDBString(1000, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public abstract class body : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Processing Filter DAC
    [Serializable]
    public partial class TestFilter : PX.Data.IBqlTable
    {
        #region LastSyncDate
        [PXDate()]
        [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Sync Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual DateTime? LastSyncDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastSyncDate : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region ProjectID
        [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Project ID")]
        public virtual String ProjectID { get; set; }
        public abstract class projectID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region IssueID
        [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Issue ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        public virtual String IssueID { get; set; }
        public abstract class issueID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion


    #region Filter + Delegate Overrides

    public PXFilter<TestFilter> Filter;
    public PXCancel<TestFilter> Cancel;

    [PXVirtualDAC]
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessing<UnboundDAC, TestFilter> UnboundView;

    protected virtual IEnumerable unboundView()
    {
        GetUnboundDACList();
        foreach (UnboundDAC item in UnboundView.Cache.Cached)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    private void GetUnboundDACList()
    {
        UnboundView.Cache.Insert(new UnboundDAC() { Id = "1", Author = "Test 1", Body = "Comment 1" });
        UnboundView.Cache.Insert(new UnboundDAC() { Id = "2", Author = "Test 2", Body = "Comment 2" });
        UnboundView.Cache.Insert(new UnboundDAC() { Id = "3", Author = "Test 3", Body = "Comment 3" });
        //return UnboundView.Cache;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor + Process

    public TestUnboundProcessing()
    {
        TestFilter filter = Filter.Current;
        UnboundView.SetProcessDelegate(delegate (List<UnboundDAC> docList)
        {
            UnboundProcessing(docList, filter);
        }
      );
    }
    #endregion

    #region Processing functions

    public static void UnboundProcessing(List<UnboundDAC> docList, TestFilter aFilter)
    {
        TestUnboundProcessing graph = CreateInstance<TestUnboundProcessing>();
        graph.SaveRecords(graph, docList, aFilter);
    }

    public void SaveRecords(TestUnboundProcessing aProcessingGraph, List<UnboundDAC> docList, TestFilter aFilter)
    {
        bool isErrorOccured = false;
        CRActivityMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CRActivityMaint>();
        foreach (UnboundDAC item in docList)
        {
            try
            {
                CRActivity addedActivity = new CRActivity();
                addedActivity.UIStatus = ActivityStatusListAttribute.Completed;
                addedActivity.Type = "N";
                addedActivity.Location = item.Id;
                addedActivity.Subject = item.Author;
                addedActivity.Body = item.Body;
                addedActivity.IsPrivate = true;
                graph.Activities.Insert(addedActivity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isErrorOccured = true;
                PXProcessing<JRComment>.SetError(docList.IndexOf(item), ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (graph.Activities.Cache.Cached.Count() > 0)
        {
            graph.Actions.PressSave();
        }

        if (isErrorOccured)
        {
            throw new PXException("One or more record processed unsuccessful");
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Filter Events

    protected virtual void TestFilter_LastSyncDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnboundView.Cache.Clear();
    }

    protected virtual void TestFilter_ProjectID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnboundView.Cache.Clear();
    }

    protected virtual void TestFilter_IssueID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnboundView.Cache.Clear();
    }

    #endregion
```